# C++ abstract class parameter error workaround

Tags: c++, parameters, abstract-class

The code snippet below produces an error:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{

public:

  virtual void print() = 0;
};

void test(A x) // ERROR: Abstract class cannot be a parameter type
{
  cout << "Hello" << endl;
}
```

Is there a solution/workaround for this error other/better than replacing

```
virtual void print() = 0;
```

with

```
virtual void print() = { }
```

EDIT: I want to be able to pass any class extending/implementing the base class A as parameter by using polymorphism (i.e.  `A* x = new B() ; test(x);` )

Cheers

Comment: Abstarct class by definition should not be instantiated all by itself. It's methods need to be overridden by the derived classes. Just curious, what are you trying to achieve by doing this ?

Comment: I want to do something like A x = new B() and pass any class extending/implementing A. I should have specified the question better I guess.

Comment: Before trying to come up with a solution/workaround we need to understand the problem. The idea of passing an abstract class as a "by value" parameter makes no sense whatsoever. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Cemre: For that to work, you have to pass your `A` either by reference or by pointer. This will also take care of the error. Passing by value simply will not work for more reasons than one.

Comment: @Cemre Polymorphism works only for pointers/references. Keep the `print()` as pure virtual in `A` while implementing it `B`. Change the `test` parameter type to what @dasblinkenlight suggested.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Since you cannot instantiate an abstract class, passing one by value is almost certainly an error; you need to pass it by pointer or by reference:

```
void test(A& x) ...
```

or

```
void test(A* x) ...
```

Passing by value will result in [*object slicing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing), with is nearly guaranteed to have unexpected (in a bad way) consequences, so the compiler flags it as an error.

Comment: I'd say it's certainly guaranteed.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore You are right, the slicing will always occur, even when there are no additional data members to slice off, because the vtable will be "sliced off" to that of the base class.

Comment: One should get in the habit of passing parameters as `const type &arg` rather than `type arg` anyway. It's better for performance, and it also prevents the bad practice of using parameters as mutable variables for working with.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, change the signature:

```
void test(A& x)
//or
void test(const A& x)
//or
void test(A* x)
```

The reason your version doesn't work is because an object of type `A` doesn't logically make sense. It's abstract. Passing a reference or pointer goes around this because the **actual** type passed as parameter is not `A`, but an implementing class of `A` (derived concrete class).

Answer (score 1):

To be absolutely clear, the problem is, whenever you define a class:

```
#include <iostream>

class foo {
  public:
    char *name = (char *)"foo";
};
```

and pass an instance of that class to a function, it creates a copy:

```
void bar(foo a) {
  a.name = (char *)"bar";
}

int main() { 
  foo x;
  bar(x);
  std::cout << x.name << std::endl; // foo
  return 0;
}
```

With regard to inheritance, it creates a copy as an instance of the base class:

```
#include <iostream>

class foo {
  public:
    char *name = (char *)"foo";
};

class bar: public foo {
  public:
    char *name = (char *)"bar";
};

void baz(foo a) {
  std::cout << a.name << std::endl;
}

int main() { 
  bar x;
  baz(x); // again, foo
  return 0;
}
```

so, by doing

```
void baz(AbstractType a) {
  ...
}
```

you're telling the compiler to copy an `AbstractType` as an instance of `AbstractType` itself, which is illegal.
Pass it as `const AbstractType &a` to prevent copying.