# Pass abstract parameter to method, why not?

Tags: c++, inheritance, subclass, base-class

I've written an abstract class (with *pure* virtual functions), and I'd like to have a method accept one such class as a parameter. Given that the class is abstract, I understand that I couldn't pass an abstract class to any method, but why can't I pass a subclass of an abstract class to that method? How do I specify that a parameter should be any of the subclasses of a specified baseclass? This is all in C++.

Comment: That's half the point of using inheritance. Just have the method take a pointer to the abstract class, then you can pass it a pointer to any derived class.

Comment: "Given that the class is abstract, I understand that I couldn't pass an abstract class to any method". This is true **only** if you limit yourself to pass by value. In general one use polymorphism ( pass by reference or pass by pointer address) when dealing with abstract, and more generally any base/mother class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the parameter as a pointer (or reference), e.g. `Abstract *` rather than `Abstract`. If `Derived` inherits from `Abstract`, you can pass a variable of type `Derived *` when `Abstract *` is expected, but you can't in general pass one of type `Derived` when `Abstract` is expected.

Comment: What's the reason for this? What's the point of restricting that usage of parameters?

Comment: @Jack Because you cannot instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: @Smac89 - even if you could, passing it by value would **slice** the object.

Comment: You can pass by **pointer** or by **reference**. And note that a **cast** is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a **conversion**. There is an implicit conversion from `Derived*` to `Abstract*` and an implicit conversion from `Derived&` to `Abstract&`. No cast needed for either one.

Comment: @Jack If you try to have your function take an `Abstract` by value, it will create a copy of the object passed in. You can't create a copy of `Abstract`, because it's abstract. And even if it wasn't abstract, only the base class portion of the object would be copied.

Passing by reference is fine, it's essentially the same as passing by a pointer just with different syntax.

Comment: @PeteBecker: What do you mean by "slice"?

Comment: @Jack - slicing occurs when you pass an object of a derived type to a function that takes an object of a base type by value. The derived object is converted to a base object, so all you get is the base part: the derived part gets sliced off.

Comment: Thanks for the notes on terminology and references - I've improved the answer. I nearly mentioned references to begin with but then had a moment of self-doubt about whether they would be covered so left it out.

Answer (score 1):

Then you use polymorphism in C++.

Given any base class:

```
struct Base{};
```

and its subclasses:

```
struct SubClassA : public Base(){};
struct SubClassB : public Base(){};
```

If you declare:

```
void MyFunctionReference(Base&){};
void MyFunctionPointer(Base*){};
```

You can then call:

```
{
   SubClassA a;
   SubClassB b;

   MyFunctionReference(a); // by reference
   MyFunctionPointer(&b); // by pointer address
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed do this, observe:

**Pure abstract class:**

```
class Abstract {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

**Child of overrides member function:**

```
class AbstractImpl : public Abstract {
public:
    void foo() override { std::cout << "Hi from subclass\n"; }
};
```

**Now we declare a method that takes a reference type of the abstract class**

```
void somefunc(Abstract &ab) {
    ab.foo();
}
```

Finally in main we instantiate the child class parameter

```
int main() {
    AbstractImpl test;
    somefunc(test); // prints Hi from subclass
    return 0;
}
```

**Source**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11422101/2089675