# Pass abstract class(all virtual, so interface) into another class's constructor with default value

Tags: c++, inheritance

I've found a few questions on Stackoverflow regarding passing in abstract classes to methods, e.g. [Pass abstract parameter to method, why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20434948/pass-abstract-parameter-to-method-why-not)

I want to try and do something like below, but I keep getting an error. I've tried various guesswork like switching to pointers, etc. But nothing really works. I also added `: c_()` after `Other`, but that didn't work either. I'm new to the language and am still figuring out how things come together.

```
#include <iostream>

class Child
{
public:
        virtual void Test() = 0;
};

class Child1 : public Child
{
public:
        void Test()
        {
                std::cout << "Child1" << std::endl;
        }
};

class Child2 : public Child
{
public:
        void Test()
        {
                std::cout << "Child2" << std::endl;
        }
};

class Other
{
Child &c_;
public:
        Other(Child &c=Child2())
        {
                c_ = c;
        }
        void which_child()
        {
                c_.Test();
        }
};

int main()
{
        Child1 c1;
        Other o(c1);
        o.which_child();
        return 0;
}
```

Error I'm getting:

```
test.cpp:31:22: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'Child' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'Child2'
        Other(Child &c=Child2())
                     ^ ~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:31:22: note: passing argument to parameter 'c' here
test.cpp:31:9: error: constructor for 'Other' must explicitly initialize the reference member 'c_'
        Other(Child &c=Child2())
        ^
test.cpp:29:8: note: declared here
Child &c_;
       ^
2 errors generated.
```

Getting this after I added `c_()`:

```
test.cpp:31:22: note: passing argument to parameter 'c' here
test.cpp:31:36: error: reference to type 'Child' requires an initializer
        Other(Child &c=Child2()) : c_()
```

Comment: You need to use [memeber initilization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Comment: can you write down the error you get?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What error are you getting, and what were you *trying* to do at the time? Since, as you say, you're new to the language, we can't really rely on the code to describe what you want to be because, being new to the language, you don't know what the code means. If you don't know, then neither can anyone else. Please describe your intention in words.

Comment: @RobKennedy Is the question "Pass abstract class(all virtual, so interface) into another class's constructor with default value" unclear?

Comment: Yes. Which parts of the title are important? Do you think the abstractness relevant? I don't know, because you didn't say so in your question. Is it important that it's the *constructor* you're passing it to, rather than some other method? Is it important that it's some *other* class and not the same one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Other(Child &c=Child2()) {
>       c_ = c; // << can't be done since references must be
>               // initialised at time of construction
> }
> ```

you need to initialize references from the constructors member initializer list:

```
Other(Child &c) : c_(c) {
}
```

Comment: Getting: test.cpp:31:22: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'Child' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'Child2'
        Other(Child &c=Child2()) : c_(c)
                     ^ ~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:31:22: note: passing argument to parameter 'c' here

Comment: @UserNotDefined Well, that says you would require a const reference or move constructor. You need to clarify what the class actually needs.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I don't want the object to be a constant.

Comment: @UserNotDefined _`= Child2()` implies a constant. Use a move constructor to retrieve rvalues.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into what you've mentioned. I also had to add `std::move(c1)`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  `= Child2()` implies a temporary. Taking the reference to that is reckless and stores a dangling reference in `c_`. Oops UB.

Comment: @sehe THX, I removed that part.